# Using the pen tool in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, graphic-styles

I am new to Adobe Illustrator, and I'm having problems with my pen tool. Every time I click on it, it makes an anchor point with a line that drags from it. It does not make individual points that connect after.

[image]

Can someone please help me remove that blue line? I have tried going to preference to see if I can change the setting but I can't seem to pin point which one it is.

Comment: Turn off the "Rubber Band" item in the preferences.